# Jhipster War generated seems to not work in 6.3.1 (standalone and tomcat)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

We are using jhipster 6.3.1 for our spring boot and angular applications. It runs fine in developement. But when we try to create war and deploy it to tomcat, it does not run.

War seems to be getting deployed properly as I can see the logs and all properly in command line.

I am using following command to create war file.

```
./gradlew -Pprod -Pwar clean bootWar
```

Please check below url for more details.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9829

Comment: please check the tomcat log file when application get start.since jhipster consist lot of built in modules and,various requirements to boot up the application,it is easy to fail most of the time,check prod profile for everythig is correct,starting from database name.. easiest way to monitor tomcat log file when application getting started right after deployment

Comment: there is no error in logs and tomcat runs properly. i think something is wrong the front end code is packaged in war. If u see the above link and see the structure of the war generated.

Comment: this can be because javascript is not injected properly.open the console and check whether it has a error.since this is issue with js building process it is better to check node version is compatible and other build related factors, and yes tomcat log shows only java errors.. jhipster is painful !!

Comment: Ok. it works when I use ROOT.war but not when I use some other context path.

Comment: Did you try configuring the context-path as documented https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ ?

Comment: What is the solution to this problem? Did you have any clues to solve the problem? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Any solutions? I have it.